# How can I call a method with popped object using commons-digester?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-commons-digester

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<items>
  <item type="java.lang.Boolean" name="foo" value="true" />
</items>
```

I'd like the `<root>` element to create a `java.util.Map` object and have each `<item>` element create an object of the appropriate type and then add an entry to the `Map` -- similar to a `SetNextRule` but with an argument to the call coming from the stack.

I've already created a custom `Rule` that will create an object of the type specified in the `type` attribute (`java.lang.Boolean` in this case) using the value in the `value` attribute and push it on the stack.

Now, I'd like to pop the item off the top of the stack and use it as an argument to the `put` method on the `Map` object (which is just "under" the `Boolean` object on the stack).

Here's the code I have written so far:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
Digester digester = new Digester();
digester.addObjectCreate("items", HashMap.class);
digester.addRule(new MyObjectCreateRule()); // This knows how to create e.g. java.lang.Boolean objects
digester.addCallMethod("items/item", "put", 2, new Class<?>[] { String.class, Object.class });
digester.addCallParam("items/item", 0, "name");
digester.addCallParam("items/item", 1, true); // take argument from stack
```

I'm getting the error that the method `put` can't be found in the `java.lang.Boolean` class. So, the problem is that the e.g. `Boolean` object is on the top of the stack, and I want to use it as an argument to the `put` method called on the next-to-top element on the stack:

Stack:

```
java.lang.Boolean value=true     <-- top of stack, desired call param
java.util.HashMap contents = {}  <-- desired call target
```

Is there a way to do this with existing commons-digester rules, or do I have to create another custom rule that performs this type of operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom rule that combined the two operations: constructing a new instance of the property value *and* inserting it into the properties bundle.

This is an adaptation of the *real* use-case that I had, so the code may not be 100% perfect since I copy/pasted and adapted it, here. I also understand that using property values other than `java.lang.String` doesn't quite make sense, but it did for my use-case (which doesn't use `java.util.Properties`, actually, but that class was a good analogy).

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
/**
 * Implements a create-object-set-property Digester rule.
 */
public class SetPropertyRule
    extends Rule
{
    private String _classAttributeName;
    private String _nameAttributeName;
    private String _valueAttributeName;
    private HashSet<String> _acceptableClassNames;

    /**
     * Creates a new SetPreferenceRule with default attribute names and classes.
     *
     * Default class attribute name = "type".
     * Default name attribute name = "name".
     * Default value attribute name = "value".
     * Default allowed classes = String, Integer, Double, and Boolean.
     */
    public SetPropertiesRule()
    {
        this("type", "name", "value",
             new Class<?>[] { String.class, Integer.class, Double.class, Boolean.class });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new SetPropertyRule to construct a name/value pair and
     * set it on a Properties object.
     *
     * The Properties object should be at the top of the current
     * Digester stack.
     *
     * @param classAttributeName The name of the attribute that holds the property's value type.
     * @param nameAttributeName The name of the attribute that holds the property's name.
     * @param valueAttributeName The name of the attribute that holds the property's value.
     * @param acceptableClasses The list of acceptable property value types.
     */
    public SetPreferenceRule(String classAttributeName, String nameAttributeName, String valueAttributeName, Class<?>[] acceptableClasses)
    {
        super();

        _classAttributeName = classAttributeName;
        _nameAttributeName = nameAttributeName;
        _valueAttributeName = valueAttributeName;
        _acceptableClassNames = new HashSet<String>(acceptableClasses.length);
        for(Class<?> clazz : acceptableClasses)
            _acceptableClassNames.add(clazz.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(String namespace,
                      String name,
                      Attributes attributes)
        throws Exception
    {
        // Store the values of these attributes on the digester param stack
        getDigester().pushParams(
                attributes.getValue(_classAttributeName),
                attributes.getValue(_nameAttributeName),
                attributes.getValue(_valueAttributeName)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void end(String namespace,
                    String name)
        throws Exception
    {
        Object[] attributeValues = getDigester().popParams();

        Object props = getDigester().peek();
        if(!(props instanceof java.util.Properties))
        {
            String typeName;
            if(null == props)
                typeName = "<null>";
            else
                typeName = props.getClass().getName();

            throw new IllegalStateException("Expected instance of " + Properties.class.getName() + ", got " + typeName + " instead");
        }

        String className = (String)attributeValues[0];
        checkClassName(className);

        // Create an instance of the preference value class
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<?> cons = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
        Object value = cons.newInstance((String)attributeValues[2]);

        ((Properties)props).put((String)attributeValues[1], value);
    }

    private void checkClassName(String className)
    {
        if(!_acceptableClassNames.contains(className))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class " + className + " is not allowed");
    }
}
```

I'd be happy to discover that there is an out-of-the-box way to do this, however.

Answer (score 0):

For a different approach, you could move the problem out of digester itself and use an enhanced map class to provide a method more compatible with the existing digester rules:

```
public static class MyHashMap extends HashMap {
  public Object put(String clazz, String name, String value) {
    Object obj = ... // create object from clazz/name/value
    return super.put(name, obj);
  }
}
```

Then just use the existing `addCallMethod` / `addCallParam` rules:

```
Digester digester = new Digester();
digester.addObjectCreate("items", MyHashMap.class);
digester.addCallMethod("items/item", "put", 3, new Class<?>[] { String.class, String.class, String.class });
digester.addCallParam("items/item", 0, "type");
digester.addCallParam("items/item", 1, "name");
digester.addCallParam("items/item", 2, "value");
```

If you needed to get a pure `HashMap` as a result rather than a custom class, you could use a similar method with your custom class wrapping a native `HashMap`, e.g.`com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap` if you are using Guava.